# Angular 8+ tsconfig Path Aliases not Recognized in .spec files

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, visual-studio-code, jestjs

I am working on some Angular testing and my spec files will not recognize my paths and they give me a red squiggle import warning in VS Code (and show up in Problems) despite the fact that they work in every other way (testing works, etc.).  I am assuming this is a tsconfig issue and not a linting issue as the error it gives me is: `Cannot find module '@feature/<reference path>.<file type>'.ts(2307)`

It functionally doesn't affect me much, but it is annoying (and kills automatic imports).

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "esnext",
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "alwaysStrict": false,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "target": "es2015",
        "types": [
            "node",
            "arcgis-js-api",
            "jest"
        ],
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "lib": [
            "es2017",
            "dom",
            "esnext.asynciterable"
        ],
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "core-js/es6/*": [
                "node_modules/core-js/es/*"
            ],
            "core-js/es7/reflect": [
                "node_modules/core-js/proposals/reflect-metadata"
            ],
            "@core/*": [
                "src/app/core/*"
            ],
            "@shared/*": [
                "src/app/shared/*"
            ],
            "@feature/*": [
                "src/app/feature/*"
            ],
            "@test/*": [
                "src/test/*"
            ],
            "@/*": [
                "src/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "files": [
        "src/main.ts",
        "src/polyfills.ts"
    ],
    "include": [
        "**/*.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

tsconfig.spec.json and tsconfig.app.json paths (note standard folder structure from angular-cli):

```
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec"
    }
}
```

angular.json

```
...
            "test": {
                "builder": "@angular-builders/jest:run",
                "options": {
                    "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
                    "no-cache": true,
                    "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                    "configPath": "./jest.config.js",
                    "styles": [
                        "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
                        "src/styles.scss"
                    ],
                    "scripts": [],
                    "assets": [
                        "src/favicon.ico",
                        "src/assets",
                        "src/manifest.json",
                    ],
                    "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
                        "includePaths": [
                            "src"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            "lint": {
                "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                "options": {
                    "tsConfig": [
                        "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                        "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
                    ],
                    "exclude": [
                        "**/node_modules/**"
                    ]
                }
            }
...
```

Versions:

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.6
Node: 12.3.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.2.8
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms     
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router, service-worker

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.803.6
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.803.6
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.803.6
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.803.6
@angular-devkit/core              8.3.6
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.3.6
@angular/cli                      8.3.6
@angular/pwa                      0.803.6
@ngtools/webpack                  8.3.6
@schematics/angular               8.3.6
@schematics/update                0.803.6
rxjs                              6.5.3
typescript                        3.5.3
webpack                           4.39.2
```

Comment: Ensure that your `tsconfig.spec.json` extends the config where you have provided `paths`. Or place these path in this config

Comment: As I show above, ` "extends": "../tsconfig.json",` I am extending it.  Additionally, I have tried putting the paths directly in; it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: If the problem is only about VSCode and despite this everything works it's worth creating an issue in VSCode github

Comment: @MapLion downgrade your typescript version to `typescript": "3.4.5"`

Comment: @Sergey I don't think it is a VSCode problem; I think it is a typescript/tsconfig issue, but I wanted to reach out to the community before clogging up issues with something that is more annoying than anything.

Comment: @JoelJoseph I attempted downgrading to 3.4.5 and still am getting the same results.  Interestingly, I seem to have a similar problem in the project itself with regular classes, interfaces, etc. until the file is referenced by the project (like the compiler won't read it and give me intellisense and map the path aliases until then).  I'm wondering if this is somehow related since the .spec files are obviously not part of the project.  I don't remember it having such a strict functionality.  Is there a setting I'm missing?  Updated to include all of my tsconfig.

Comment: Perhaps one of my tsconfig settings is doing something that I don't expect.

Comment: try removing src/app/ from the path worked for me...

Comment: I had the same problem, In my case in exclude I had "**/*.d.ts". Removing that fixed it :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I imagine the issue is related to your `files` and `include` configuration. When I included your rather limited set of `files` and `include` patterns I instantly saw the same issue you describe for the simple reason that not all of my files match `*.d.ts`.

To see if this is what is causing the issue for you (or if you know that you have files not matched by `*.d.ts`), I'd recommend starting by simply removing your `files` and `include` sections, saving `tsconfig.json` and restarting the TS server in VS Code.

For those that don't know, you can restart the TS server in VS Code by opening the Command Palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> or just <kbd>F1</kbd>) within a `.ts` file and typing `Restart TS` and selecting that command.

If that *is* the solution for you, then you just need to think about what you actually need in `files` and `include`. The [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#details) should help on that front.

The biggest takeaway: you don't *need* either of them:

> If the "files" and "include" are both left unspecified, the compiler defaults to including all TypeScript (.ts, .d.ts and .tsx) files in the containing directory and subdirectories except those excluded using the "exclude" property. JS files (.js and .jsx) are also included if allowJs is set to true.

If you do need that specificity, you may just need to add `*.ts` and\or `*.tsx` patterns to your `include` patterns to solve the issue.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you sir.  You made my day and are my first rewarded bounty.  I don't fully understand the behavior yet, but I'm really glad to have it resolved.

Comment: I'm glad that helped!

Re: the behavior of `files` and `include`: By default all Typescript files are included, unless you pass in a list of specific files via the command line or `tsconfig.json`, or a pattern to include via `include`. You can also *exclude* specific patterns via `exclude` in your `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: That helped me fix my own issue. Mine was related to webpack path aliases which I was using in my TS/ JS, and those paths need to be notified to the Typescript system or it fails to find them. My fix was to add "paths" for each webpack alias to the tsconfig.json file.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I forgot to setup `jest.config.js` file according of my project.

```
tsconfig.ts
...
"@app/*": ["src/app/*"],
...
```

and

```
jest.config.js

module.exports = {
    moduleNameMapper: {
        "@app/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/app/$1"
    } 
};
```

Reference: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulenamemapper-objectstring-string--arraystring

Answer (score 4):

tsconfig.ts

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ....
    "paths": {
      "@app1/*" : ["src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

packages.json

```
  "jest": {
    ...
    "rootDir": "src",
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "@app1/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/$1"
    } 
  }
```